# Bake won't look same as render

Tags: rendering, texture-baking

I have an object that is given colour with a lot of sun lamps, then I did some compositing to my liking.

Here is what I have:

[image]

Now I want to add another object below it to be render with the banana but the sun lamps will affect the colour of the second object which is why I wanted to bake it so I can remove the sun lamps and still have the same colour but on a uv and have one plain lighting that will show both objects and its textures.

Now when I bake it I don't get the same effect I would in render. When its baked it looks much darker and when rendered the colour is gone could someone explain why as well as is there a way to bake everything on a object including there compositing as well. Thank you in advance.

Here is the baked texture:

[image]

Here's a quick image:

[image]

Comment: This is partially because of the world color(bright yellow? really?) try changing it to black, or the default grey and re-adjust your lamps as needed.

Comment: I have multiple sun lamps for first image giving it the yellow colour. I am trying to bake it so I won't need the sun lamps to give it the colour it will be on a uv. Otherwise if i reajusted the lamp as needed the objects will be affected aswell.